# Multiple argument IF statement - T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

How do I write an IF statement with multiple arguments in T-SQL?

Current source error:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME

SET @StartDate = NULL
SET @EndDate = NULL

IF (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        -- do some work
    END
```

It throws the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'AND'. Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'AND'. Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

Comment: Works on my machine?  I'm thinking the error might be between your `BEGIN` and `END`.  Or, if you have nothing between the `BEGIN` and `END`, that would be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  It was the `--do some work` section that was causing the issue.  I am building a dynamic SQL statement...ugh!

Comment: I get `Incorrect syntax near 'END'.` because of the empty block. Put `x:` before the comment (or a real statement).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are doing it right.   The empty code block is what is causing your issue.  It's not the condition structure :)

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME

DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME

SET @StartDate = NULL
SET @EndDate = NULL

IF (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        print 'yoyoyo'
    END

IF (@StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL AND 1=1 AND 2=2) 
    BEGIN
        print 'Oh hey there'
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is valid (with one exception).  It is required to have code between BEGIN and END.

Replace

```
--do some work
```

with

```
print ''
```

I think maybe you saw "END and not "AND"

Answer (score 1):

That's the way to create complex boolean expressions: combine them with AND and OR. The snippet you posted doesn't throw any error for the IF.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine.

If you have an empty **BEGIN ... END**  block you might see

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is, this seems to work just fine?

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME

SET @StartDate = NULL
SET @EndDate = NULL

IF (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        Select 'This works just fine' as Msg
    END
Else
    BEGIN
    Select 'No Lol' as Msg
    END
```